# List of key codes (InputProcessor)

Tags: java, input, libgdx

Interface `InputProcessor` implements the `keyUp` and `keyDown` methods that pass key-codes in `int`. Where can I find a list of these codes corresponding to keyboard input?

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }
```

Let's say i want to map `UP` to a event. How do I know the keycode of `UP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.Keys.html. Note that you could have followed the link from the [javadocs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html#keyUp-int-):

> keycode - one of the constants in Input.Keys

Comment: I am getting an int... I assume i cannot do if (keycode == 'UP')

Comment: Unlike keyTyped which returns a `char`

Comment: Since my question did not have a obvious answer I figured there must be something wrong with my thinking. Solved my problem with `(keycode == Input.Keys.Up)`. Still, there should be an `int` involved, so is there a list of these `integers`?

Comment: You mean that you want to see a list of the actual values? Sure, here it is: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.java#L68, but you should never need those values, nor depend on them. Instead just use the static variables, like you did in your comment.